# How do I set a UITextField's borderColor?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to set a `UITextField`'s `borderColor` in iOS 8 in Swift. I tried using this code:

```
myTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor( red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue:0, alpha: 1.0 )
```

I got this error:

> UIColor not convertible to CGColor

Answer (score 41):

@coderRed gave you an Objective C answer and a Swift answer. Ignore his first Line

I broke it up into 2 statements below in Swift:

```
let myColor : UIColor = UIColor( red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue:0, alpha: 1.0 )
myTextField.layer.borderColor = myColor.CGColor
```

Hope this helps! Good luck with learning Swift

Comment: @weePee It is not showing any error but the border color is not changed. It was my first day with Swift.

Comment: You need to explicity set myTextField.layer.borderWidth to at least 1 in order to see it.

Comment: First I added input from storyboard, and then When I try to set border width and its colour, [this](http://img42.com/hz2mj+) happens.. It doesn't override the default border. It is like there are duplicate borders..

Answer (score 34):

You can try this,it works for me

```
myTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
myTextField.layer.masksToBounds = true
myTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor( red: 153/255, green: 153/255, blue:0/255, alpha: 1.0 ).CGColor
myTextField.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
```

Comment: I really like the use of the 153/255, it makes the RGB values very clear, rather than the decimal values. +1

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
myTextField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

myTextField.layer.borderColor = (UIColor( red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue:0, alpha: 1.0 )).CGColor;
```

Comment: Thnaks for the reply. I tried it and I am getting "expected declaration" error. Sorry I am new to iOS programming.

Answer (score 10):

I believe you need to set the borderWidth

```
myTextField.layer.borderWidth = 10
```

Answer (score 9):

I found that the simplest way to set the border color using Swift 3 is to do

```
myTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
```

or

```
myTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
```

Hope this works!
Good luck.

Comment: I went with this. THanks

Answer (score 5):

You might also want to add line like:

```
myTextField.layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(1.0)
```

To previous answers.

In my case, color change wasn't visible, until I placed this line.

Comment: this was the solution to my issue, thanks a bundle!!!

Answer (score 4):

The issue with this is about converting a UIColor to a CGColor, which is explained in the above answers, but put most simply, all you have to do to do this conversion is add `.CGColor` to the end of your UIColor. i.e.

```
myTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor( red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue:CGFLoat, alpha: CGFloat ).CGColor
```

Answer (score 3):

```
myTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
extension UITextField{
    func setBorderColor(width:CGFloat,color:UIColor) -> Void{
        self.layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = width
    }
}
```

and implement this function wherever you want,

```
 textField.setBorderColor(width: 2.0, color: UIColor.brown)
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

```
myTextField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
myTextField.layer.borderColor = (UIColor( red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue:0, alpha: 1.0 )).CGColor;
```

What I do in swift and what ALWAYS works:

```
myTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor;
myTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue:0, alpha: 1.0 ).CGColor;
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

`myTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor( red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue:0, alpha: 1.0 ).cgColor` ?

You can also cast the color `as! CGColor` but using the `.cgColor` at the end is preferes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `cgColor` property. I also think you need to set `borderWidth` in order for it to work.
Example:

```swift
textfield.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
textfield.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor // Use CGColor
```

You might find it handy to make an extension, so that it will be usable by other views.

```swift
extension UIView {
    func addBorderAndColor(color: UIColor, width: CGFloat, corner_radius: CGFloat = 0, clipsToBounds: Bool = false) {
        self.layer.borderWidth  = width
        self.layer.borderColor  = color.cgColor
        self.layer.cornerRadius = corner_radius
        self.clipsToBounds      = clipsToBounds
    }
}
```

Call this like:

```swift
textfield.addBorderAndColor(color: UIColor.white, width: 0.5, corner_radius: 5, clipsToBounds: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following code in your viewDidLoad method:

```
textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black
textField.layer.borderColor = (UIColor(red:0.5,green:0.5,blue:1,alpha:1.0))
```